# Split Django input field and store into separate rows of record

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Here's what I am trying achieve but not sure how to make it happen.

I am building a literature analytic tool. User will paste some text into a field, the system will split word by word into a database table one row for each word, and they have to be sequential. By doing so, later then we can edit and define the translation/annotation of each word.

I am new to Django and hvn't figure out the whole logic behind it yet, but I am curious if it is achievable.

First things first, from the tutorial I just been through from the official Django website, every field created equals to a "cell" in a database table, so what happens if I want to split the content in the input field and store them rows of data in a database table with an ID incremented to index the order of them?

Second, if the above is achieved, when i need to add a word(record) in the middle of the database, like adding something in the middle of an array, is it achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if what you're asking but this is how I would do it based on what you have said

```
# models 
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField("""field args""")

# Views
words = form.cleaned_data['sentance'].split(" ")
for word in words:
    _ = Word.objects.create(word=word)
```